# Qt 5.1 for android occurs error in apache-ant

Tags: android, qt, ant

The Qt5.1 for android is out now ,so I just try it. Well, after I installed Android SDK, Android NDK, openJDK and apache-ant , I start the Qt creator but I fail to work it. Error below:

```
error: packing:'/opt/apache-ant-1.9.1/bootstrap/bin/ant clean debug'command
failed. Exit code: 1
```

How to make through it ? Best Regards:-)

---

I find that my ant cannot work well! In my /opt/apache-ant-1.9.1 directory, I run bootstrap.sh first and then build.sh. All "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" . But when I run "ant" in my torminal:

```
ERROR: cannot find or load the main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

But I really find the classes in "/opt/apache-ant-1.9.1/build/classes/org/apache/tools/ant/launch" directory.How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message.
After I use apt-get install ant (in debian), it works normal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Preference ---> Android ---> JDK Location to 
eg for Mac:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home